Increasing water flow in residential well system
The system is plumbed as follows: well pump -> pressure switch -> two 35 gal. accumulator tanks in parallel -> 2.5 cu ft pH adjustment tank -> 2.5 cu ft iron removal tank 1 -> 2.5 cu ft iron removal tank 2 -> 2.5 cu ft softener tank -> 3/4" tubing to distribution manifold. Pressure and flow are good until multiple fixtures are open where one is a high flow fixture. I assume that the 4-tank treatment system is restricting flow. Wondering whether an accumulator tank and check valve downstream of the treatment tanks would help or if a booster pump is needed.

What pressure is the switch set for?  Most systems have low flow when multiple fixtures are open.  The one pipe from the well can only flow so much water at a time.  Water pressure should be kept below 80psi.

The pressure switch is set 40/60.

That is good pressure, not too high to damage pipes and not too low to run a couple of fixtures.
